# opposite of click function

Tags: javascript, checkbox, onclick

what is the opposite function if the user unclicks a checkbox?

this is my script if the user clicks the checkbox

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("input[name$='INopt']").click(function() {
    $("#OUTsrvOtr").prop('class','text')
    });
});
</script>

 <input id="INsrv" name="INopt" type="checkbox" value="1" />1<br>
```

but i want this to run if the user unclicks/unchecks the checkbox

```
$("#OUTsrvOtr").prop('class','validate[required] text-input text')
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Inside click method you can check if if checkbox is checked or unchecked

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("input[name$='INopt']").click(function() {
   if(this.checked){
        $("#OUTsrvOtr").prop('class','text');
     }
      else{
          $("#OUTsrvOtr").prop('class','validate[required] text-input text');
     }

    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: is it ok if i use it on the checkbox id?  $("#INsrv").click(function() {

Comment: Sorry,I did not get it. whose value did you changed?

Comment: insted of the  $("input[name$='INopt']").click(function() that detects the name i want it to detect the ID of the checkbox, that is id="INsrv", so will this be accurate if i do this $("#INsrv").click(function(), because when i changed it to search for the id it stops working/

Comment: then you should use  $("input[name$='INopt']"). is there any other element with id=INsrv. just want to know. I have created jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/sF8fS/.

Comment: <input id="OUTsrv17" name="OUTopt" type="checkbox" value="Other" />

Comment: there are 17 checkboxes that are all similar in names but aren't similar in ID's

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/17363/discussion-between-shusl-and-telexper)

Answer (score 1):

It's still click, only you need to check `this.checked` - if it's `true` then the box has been checked, otherwise (for unchecking it) it's `false`.